# How to make a game move continuously

Tags: c#

I'm trying to program a game called NIM (https://plus.maths.org/content/play-win-nim). I've got halfway through, however, when a player makes a move, the board will simply reset to normal for the next move. Any thoughts on how I can make another move to the board and it takes into account the previous move?

```
    static string underline = "\x1B[4m";
    static string reset = "\x1B[0m";
    static string firstMove;
    static bool gameStatus = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Introduction();
        InitialBoardSetUp();
        PlayingGame();
    }
    static void Introduction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t" + underline + "Welcome to NIM!\n"+ reset);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(underline + "The rules are as follows:\n" + reset);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("   - Each player takes their turn to remove a certain number of 'blocks' from a stack, of which there are 7.");
        Console.WriteLine("   - This happens until there is only 1 'block' remaining. With the winner being the one to remove the last 'block'.\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
    }
    static void InitialBoardSetUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(underline + "This is how the board is formatted:\n" + reset);
        Thread.Sleep(750);

        Console.Write("     ");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("  " + i + "    ");
        }

        Console.Write("\n\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("  " + i + "   ");

            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("███    ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    static void WhoGoesFirst()
    {
        string[] PossibleChoices = { "Computer", "You" };

        Random WhoGoesFirst = new Random();
        int WGFIndex = WhoGoesFirst.Next(0, 2);

        firstMove = PossibleChoices[WGFIndex];

        Console.WriteLine("Randomly selecting who goes first...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} will go first!\n", firstMove);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    static void ComputerMove()
    {
        Random CompStack = new Random();
        int CompStackSelection = CompStack.Next(1, 8);

        Random CompRemoved = new Random();
        int CompRemovedSelection = CompRemoved.Next(1, 8);

        Console.WriteLine("Computer is making its move... ");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Computer has decided to remove {0} blocks from stack number {1}.\n", CompRemovedSelection, CompStackSelection);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.Write("     ");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("  " + i + "    ");
        }

        Console.Write("\n\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("  " + i + "   ");

            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
            {
                if (j == CompStackSelection && i <= CompRemovedSelection)
                {
                    Console.Write("       ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("███    ");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    static void PlayerMove()
    {
        Console.Write("Which stack do you wish to remove from?: ");
        int PlayerStackSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Exception Handling - Can't be greater than 7 or less than 1.

        Console.Write("How many blocks do you wish to remove?: ");
        int PlayerRemovedSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Exception Handling - Can't be greater than 7 or less than 1.

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("     ");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("  " + i + "    ");
        }

        Console.Write("\n\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("  " + i + "   ");

            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
            {
                if (j == PlayerStackSelection && i <= PlayerRemovedSelection)
                {
                    Console.Write("       ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("███    ");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    static void PlayingGame()
    {
        int gameNumber = 1;

        while (gameStatus == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(underline + "Round " + gameNumber+ ":\n" + reset);
            
            WhoGoesFirst();

            if (firstMove == "Computer")
            {
                ComputerMove();
            }
            else
            {
                PlayerMove();
            }

            gameNumber += 1;

            playAgain();
        }
    }
    static void playAgain()
    {
        Console.Write("Do you wish to play again? (Y/N): ");
        char playAgain = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        if (playAgain == 'Y')
        {
            gameStatus = true;
        }
        else if (playAgain == 'N')
        {
            gameStatus = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `PlayingGame()` you need to create a game loop.

```
static void PlayingGame()
{
    int turn =  // randomly choose 0 or 1 (whose turn is it)
    bool finished = false;
    while(!finished)
    {
        if(turn==0) 
        {
            ComputerMove();
        } else {
            PlayerMove();
        }
        finished = CheckForEndOfGame();
        turn = 1 - turn;
    }
}
```

I do **strongly suggest** to create a `Game` class that handles the logic of the game and separate the UI (like messages etc) from the game mechanics. This is `C#` after all, and object oriented approaches are strongly encouraged.

You need to keep track of that game board and whose turn it is and what has been played in this `Game` class and display on the screen things based on the values (the state) of the game.